# phpMyAdmin: Delete button is not functioning

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have XAMPP v3.2.2 for Windows installed on my local machine and I cannot delete records from my tables via phpMyAdmin.

Here is a screenshot with the error that I am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlmtE.jpg. From what I see, the SQL query generated when clicking on the delete button isn't correct, but I don't know how to solve this.

Could it be because I changed the my.ini config file and set `lower_case_table_names = 2`? This is the only change I did to the my.ini file.

Here is the table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Followups`
--

CREATE TABLE `Followups` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ContactID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `RMID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Number` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for table `Followups`
--
ALTER TABLE `Followups`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `Followups`
--
ALTER TABLE `Followups`
  MODIFY `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I tried to make a copy of the table using only lowercase letters in the table name and I could delete records from that table. So I guess the problem is, as I thought, caused by the `lower_case_table_names` parameter from the my.ini file. Any ideas on what can I do next to solve this problem without having to rename all my table names?

Comment: Please write condition after where

Comment: The sql query isn't written by me. I know it has errors, but it is generated once I click the Delete button.

Answer (score 0):

This is not phpMyAdmin problem.  Here delete is wrong. According to your screenshot sql query shows as "Delete FROM 'followups'" where limit 1" But you do not have where condition. Thats the issue.

I think you have no set primary key for this table

Comment: I think it is a phpMyAdmin problem rather because an element from the UI of the phpMyAdmin isn't doing what it is supposed to do probably because of some of the settings in the my.ini file. I have a primary key set for this table. I will edit the question and add the table structure.